# Verilog finite state machine won't reset (asynchronous) current state to initial state (shows xx)

Tags: verilog, simulation, clock, reset, system-verilog

I have mostly worked on VHDL and I have recently started learning Verilog.

I wrote a Moore Finite State Machine (FSM). The FSM is not resetting properly as current state upon reset doesn't go into initial state as indicated by its value cstat = xx by simulator at t=0. Also the output which depends upon cstate is also shown as oup1 = x.

The design and testbench is on EDA playground (https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Uwi). With Cadence Incisive 15.20 simulator invoked with command line options

> -timescale 1ms/1us -sysv -disable_sem2009

I get following log output showing the simulation failed:

```
[2020-03-09 15:12:36 EDT] irun -Q -unbuffered '-timescale' '1ms/1us' '-sysv' '-disable_sem2009' '-access' '+rw' design.sv testbench.sv  
irun: 15.20-s038: (c) Copyright 1995-2017 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
    Top level design units:
        moore_fsm_tb
Loading snapshot worklib.moore_fsm_tb:sv .................... Done
ncsim> source /incisiv/15.20/tools/inca/files/ncsimrc
ncsim> run
FAILED
Time=0, rst=0, inp1=0, inp2=0, current state = xx, next state = 00, oup1 = x
Expected current state = 00, next state = 00, oup1 = 0
Simulation complete via $finish(1) at time 0 FS + 4
./testbench.sv:70       $finish;
ncsim> exit
Done
```

Design

```
module moore_fsm_top ( input wire clk,
                   input wire rst,
                   input wire inp1,
                   input wire inp2,
                   output reg oup1,
                   output reg [1:0] cstat,
                   output reg [1:0] nstat
                  );


  localparam  MAX = 4000;
  reg [11:0] ccnt;
  reg [11:0] ncnt;
  wire maxedout;

  localparam  INP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  INP_Y = 1'b1; 
  localparam  OUP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  OUP_Y = 1'b1;

  localparam  UU = 2'b00;
  localparam  VV = 2'b01;
  localparam  WW = 2'b10;
  localparam  XX = 2'b11;

  always @ ( posedge clk, posedge rst ) begin
    if ( rst ) begin
      cstat <= UU;
    end else begin
      cstat <= nstat;
    end
  end

  always @ ( posedge clk, posedge rst ) begin
    if ( rst ) begin
      ccnt <= 12'b0;
    end else begin
      ccnt <= ncnt;
    end
  end

  always @ ( * ) begin
      case (cstat)
        UU, WW: ncnt = 12'b0;
        VV, XX: begin
          if (ccnt == (MAX-1)) begin
            ncnt = 12'b0;
          end else begin
            ncnt = ccnt+1;
          end
        end
    endcase
  end

  assign maxedout = (ccnt == (MAX-1)) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

  always @ ( * ) begin
    case (cstat)
      UU: begin
        nstat = UU;
        if (inp1 == INP_X) begin
          nstat = UU;
        end else if (inp1 == INP_Y) begin
          nstat = VV;
        end
      end

      VV: begin
        nstat = VV;
        if (inp2 == INP_X && !maxedout ) begin
          nstat = VV;
        end else if (inp2 == INP_X && maxedout) begin
          nstat = UU;
        end else if (inp2 == INP_Y && !maxedout) begin
          nstat = WW;
        end else if (inp2 == INP_Y && maxedout) begin
          nstat = WW;
        end
      end

      WW: begin
        nstat = WW;
        if (inp2 == INP_X) begin
          nstat = WW;
        end else if (inp2 == INP_Y) begin
          nstat = XX;
        end
      end

      XX: begin
        nstat = XX;
        if (inp1 == INP_X && maxedout == 1'b0 ) begin
          nstat = XX;
        end else if (inp1 == INP_X && maxedout == 1'b1) begin
          nstat = WW;
        end else if (inp1 == INP_Y && maxedout == 1'b0) begin
          nstat = UU;
        end else if (inp1 == INP_Y && maxedout == 1'b1) begin
          nstat = UU;
        end
      end

      default: nstat = UU;
    endcase
  end

  always @ ( * ) begin
    case (cstat)
      UU, VV:   oup1 = OUP_X;
      WW, XX:   oup1 = OUP_Y;
      default:  oup1 = OUP_X;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

**Testbench**

```
`timescale 1ms / 1us

module moore_fsm_tb;

  reg clk;
  reg rst;
  reg inp1;
  reg inp2;

  wire oup1;
  wire [1:0] cstat;
  wire [1:0] nstat;

  localparam  TIME_PERIOD = 1;

  localparam  INP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  INP_Y = 1'b1;
  localparam  OUP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  OUP_Y = 1'b1;

  localparam  UU = 2'b00;
  localparam  VV = 2'b01;
  localparam  WW = 2'b10;
  localparam  XX = 2'b11;

  moore_fsm_top dut(.clk(clk),
                     .rst(rst),
                     .inp1(inp1),
                     .inp2(inp2),
                     .oup1(oup1),
                     .cstat(cstat),
                     .nstat(nstat));


  initial begin
    clk = 1'b0;
    forever #(TIME_PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;
  end

  initial begin
    rst = 1'b1;
    @(negedge clk);
    @(negedge clk);
    rst = 1'b0;
  end

  initial begin
    inp1 = INP_X;
    inp2 = INP_X;

    @(negedge rst);

    checkifgood(UU, UU, OUP_X);

    $display("PASS");
    $finish;
  end

  task checkifgood;
    input [1:0] exp_cstat;
    input [1:0] exp_nstat;
    input exp_oup1;

    if (oup1 !== exp_oup1 || cstat !== exp_cstat || nstat !== exp_nstat) begin
      $display("FAILED");
      $display("Time=%0d, rst=%0b, inp1=%d, inp2=%d, current state = %b, next state = %b, oup1 = %d",
               $time, rst, inp1, inp2, cstat, nstat, oup1 );
      $display("Expected current state = %b, next state = %b, oup1 = %d",
                exp_cstat, exp_nstat, exp_oup1 );
      $finish;
    end else begin
    $display("Time=%0d, rst=%0b, inp1=%d, inp2=%d, current state = %b, next state = %b, oup1 = %d",
             $time, rst, inp1, inp2, cstat, nstat, oup1 );
    end
  endtask

endmodule
```

I read Verilog gotcha that for asynchronous resets, if clocking and reset are in different initial blocks, than I should initialize clock and reset  with non-blocking statement. If I make this change in  above testbench, I get output from simulator saying:

```
Execution interrupted or reached maximum runtime.
```

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes. But UU = 2'b00 and it shows cstat instead as xx. reset is asynchronous active high. Its held high for 2 negedges of clk and goes to 0 after that. by that time cstat should be 0. but it isn't

Comment: @BrianDrummond Oops, I didn't see that. I will delete my comment. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: *"I read Verilog gotcha..."* That is nonsense. I always use `reset_n= 1'b0; #(TIME_PERIOD*10); reset_n= 1'b1;` I also prefer my TIME_PERIOD to be a nice big number 50 or 100 , not 1! OH! Just quickly scanning your code this is wrong: `ncnt = ncnt+1;` That does not work in a  combinatorial section.

Comment: Found more: you are changing `ncnt` in different sections. You can't do that . 1/ It gives race conditions 2/ You can not synthesize that.

Comment: @Oldfart thanks for pointing those out. Those were unintentionally done when I was obfuscating the code. I fixed them. But sill getting xx in current state and output indicating design is not getting reset: FAILED
Time=0, rst=0, inp1=0, inp2=0, current state = xx, next state = 00, oup1 = x
Expected current state = 00, next state = 00, oup1 = 0

Comment: @Oldfart Ok as you pointed out TIME_PERIOD=1 was the problem. When I change TIME_PERIOD to 2 or more the clock runs fine.But I wonder why this doesnt work because work time-precision is 1 us and even when I divided TIME_PERIOD by two to generate the clock, it should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your Test Bench and Design code, now u wont encounter the crash issue but i definitely think there is an issue in your stimulus in Test Bench.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns

module moore_fsm_tb;

  reg clk;
  reg rst;
  reg inp1;
  reg inp2;

  wire oup1;
  wire [1:0] cstat;
  wire [1:0] nstat;

  localparam  TIME_PERIOD = 2;

  localparam  INP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  INP_Y = 1'b1;
  localparam  OUP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  OUP_Y = 1'b1;

  localparam  UU = 2'b00;
  localparam  VV = 2'b01;
  localparam  WW = 2'b10;
  localparam  XX = 2'b11;

  moore_fsm_top dut(.clk(clk),
                     .rst(rst),
                     .inp1(inp1),
                     .inp2(inp2),
                     .oup1(oup1),
                     .cstat(cstat),
                     .nstat(nstat));


  initial 
    clk = 1'b0;
     always #(TIME_PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;


  initial begin
    rst = 1'b0;
    @(negedge clk);
    @(negedge clk);
    rst = 1'b1;

    @(negedge clk);
    @(negedge clk);
    rst = 1'b0;
  end

  initial begin
    inp1 = INP_X;
    inp2 = INP_X;

    @(negedge rst);

    checkifgood(UU, UU, OUP_X);

    $display("PASS");
    $finish;
  end

  task checkifgood;
    input [1:0] exp_cstat;
    input [1:0] exp_nstat;
    input exp_oup1;

    if (oup1 !== exp_oup1 || cstat !== exp_cstat || nstat !== exp_nstat) begin
      $display("FAILED");
      $display("Time=%0d, rst=%0b, inp1=%d, inp2=%d, current state = %b, next state = %b, oup1 = %d",
               $time, rst, inp1, inp2, cstat, nstat, oup1 );
      $display("Expected current state = %b, next state = %b, oup1 = %d",
                exp_cstat, exp_nstat, exp_oup1 );
      $finish;
    end else begin
    $display("Time=%0d, rst=%0b, inp1=%d, inp2=%d, current state = %b, next state = %b, oup1 = %d",
             $time, rst, inp1, inp2, cstat, nstat, oup1 );
    end
  endtask

endmodule
```

design code also modified ,but i am not sure u are trying to implement a priority encoders using the nested if-else-if structure in your design , but with initial glance i think u are not intended to do it.

```
module moore_fsm_top (
   input wire       clk,rst,inp1,inp2
  ,output reg       oup1
  ,output reg [1:0] cstat,nstat
 );

  localparam  MAX = 4000;
  reg [11:0] ccnt;
  reg [11:0] ncnt;
  wire maxedout;

  localparam  INP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  INP_Y = 1'b1;
  localparam  OUP_X = 1'b0;
  localparam  OUP_Y = 1'b1;

  localparam  UU = 2'b00;
  localparam  VV = 2'b01;
  localparam  WW = 2'b10;
  localparam  XX = 2'b11;

 always @ ( posedge clk, posedge rst )
    if ( rst ) begin
      cstat <= #1 UU;
      ccnt  <= #1 12'b0;
    end else begin
      cstat <= #1 nstat;
      ccnt  <= #1 ncnt;
    end

  always @*
      case (cstat)
        UU, WW:                      ncnt = 12'b0;
        VV, XX: if (ccnt == (MAX-1)) ncnt = 12'b0;
                else                 ncnt = ccnt+1;
    endcase

  assign maxedout = (ccnt == (MAX-1)) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

   always@* begin
                                                 nstat = cstat;
    case (cstat)
      UU:        if (inp1 == INP_Y)              nstat = VV;

      VV:        if (inp2 == INP_X &&  maxedout) nstat = UU;
            else if (inp2 == INP_Y )             nstat = WW;

      WW:        if (inp2 == INP_Y)              nstat = XX;

      XX:        if (inp1 == INP_X &&  maxedout) nstat = WW;
            else if (inp1 == INP_Y )             nstat = UU;
    endcase
  end

  always @*
    case (cstat)
      WW, XX:   oup1 = OUP_Y;
      default:  oup1 = OUP_X;
    endcase

endmodule
```

Comment: dear rama. I already found the problem and fixed it with help of @oldfart. The problem in design was not deliberate. I was obfuscating the code before I posted it here and it introduced the problem. The problem was there in Test-bench. It was basically that time period of 1 was not letting simulator proceed. Dividing time period of 1 (1 ms) by 2 in clock generation was perhaps causing it. Not sure why that is so because it should still work as time precision or step size is 1 us and so simulator should be able to generate 500 us clock edges

Comment: I think you have used localparam in the test bench by default localparam is an integer so if you divide 1 by 2 it might have rounded it to 0 so your test bench is not moving ahead and it is using up the memory, and regarding the current state is xxx, this is because in the initial block u are asserting the reset from timestamp 0 so design won't see as posedge in reset and your design won't get reset asynchronously.. So I modified the localparam,reset assertion and time precision in the Test Bench.